# How to show: there exists a 'choice function' $g:B\rightarrow A$ such that $f\circ g \circ f=f$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the following question:

> Prove that for every function $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $A$ non-empty, there exists a 'choice function' $g:B\rightarrow A$ such that $f\circ g \circ f=f$

I know that the function $g$ has to be $g(b)=a$ for $b\in B$, and $a\in f^{-1}(B)=A$.  My question is, do I have to worry about the case for $b'\in B\setminus f(A)$, since $f$ is not assumed to be surjective in the outset. If, I do, how do i account for it when constructing the function $g$.
Lastly, why is $g$ call a "choice" function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To start, given a particular $b$, how do you figure out what $g(b)$ is?

Comment: @TomKern we want $b\in f(A)$ so that $g(b)\in f^{-1}(B)=A$

Comment: If $f(r)=f(s)=t$, then $g$ "chooses" one of the values $r,s$ to be $g(t)$. That's why $g$ is called a choice function.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but we don't know if $f(r)=f(s)=t$.   There was nothing to go by for $f$ other than it maps from one set to another.  Maybe I am missing something from your explanations.

Comment: We know that if $r$ and $s$ are in the domain of $f$, then $f$ maps them each to something. If $f$ maps them to different things, there's no problem. But if $f$ maps them to the same thing, $t$, then $g$ chooses one of the inverse images of $t$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the "choice" bit, takes care of the fact that whether $f$ is one to one?   The way $g$ is defined takes care of the fact of whether $f$ is onto?  Is this correct?

Comment: If $f$ is one-one, choice is not an issue; each element of the range has a single inverse image, so no choices need to be made. If $f$ is not one-one, then $g$ has to choose one inverse image from among those available, in order to satisfy $f\circ g\circ f=f$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but whether $f$ is one to one is independent of the fact of how $g$ is defined as in azif00's answer.  I mean $g$  in either case has to be defined in a piece wise fashion where either $b\in F(A)$ or $b\in B\setminus f(A)$.

Comment: You wanted to know why $g$ is called a choice function. I'm just trying to answer that question for you. $g$ is called a choice function because, if $f$ is not one-one, then $g$ makes a choice of inverse image.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ah ok ok.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $b \in f(A)$, *choose* $a_b \in A$ such that $f(a_b)=b$.
Since $A$ is non-empty, let $a \in A$. Define $g \colon B \to A$ as
$$
g(b) = \begin{cases}
a_b & \textrm{if } b \in f(A), \\
a & \textrm{if } b \in B \setminus f(A).
\end{cases}
$$
Note that for each $x \in A$ we have $g(f(x)) = a_{f(x)}$, so that
$$
f(g(f(x))) = f(a_{f(x)}) = f(x).
$$
Therefore $f \circ g \circ f = f$.

Comment: can I ask the meaning of the notation $a_{f(x)}$.  Does it have anything to do with whether $g(b)=a$ or $g(b)=a_{b}$. Thank you.

Comment: @Seth Given $x \in A$, $a_{f(x)}$ is just $a_b$ for $b=f(x)$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.